# How to approximate $\prod\limits_{(i, j)\in I^2} (1 - \alpha_i x_{i, j})\;$ as a linear function?

Tags: calculus, functions, summation, power-series, products

Suppose we have a finite set $I \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, and  $\alpha_i\in [0, 1]$ are fixed numbers for all $i\in I$.

Is there a way to approximate  $\prod\limits_{(i, j)\in I^2} (1 - \alpha_i x_{i, j})$, where $0\leq x_{i, j}\leq 1 \; \forall (i, j)\in I^2$, as a linear function in terms of the $x_{i, j}$?
If so, how accurate is the approximation to the actual product?

Comment: For any differentiable function (not just this one), the first order approximation $f(\vec x_0) + \nabla f(\vec x_0)\cdot (\vec x-\vec x_0)$ is the best linear approximation near the point $\vec x_0$. For example, near $\vec 0$ the best linear approximation to your function is $1-\sum_{i=1}^k x_i$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for the response. I realized my question was too reduced though. I updated the question to capture the full nuance of my problem.

Comment: OR sorry, I think your answer would still work for this updated problem

Comment: Is there a norm you have in mind? A uniform approximation will differ from an $L^2$ approximation, and both from a Taylor series.

Comment: OP, best to state your application.

Comment: @graphtheory123 The comment of [A rural reader](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/874661/a-rural-reader) is a good one. Why do you want to perform such approximation on such a simple function? Is the root of the question a *real life* topic? If so, which one? Or is it an exercise ?